# How can I determine if svelte is used on a site?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to find sites that use svelte and am wondering (with puppeteer) how i can ascertain if svelte is used.

How do I do this programmatically?

Comment: Dunno about Puppeteer, but there's a browser extension called Wappalyzer (https://www.wappalyzer.com/) that might possibly be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell for certain. However, searching for css classes which start with `svelte-` is one way, since Svelte scopes CSS by creating a unique hash and prefixing your CSS classes with it.

Currently, this prefix cannot be changed.

Comment: I don't know puppeteer but something like
```
const elements = page.$$('div[class^="svelte-"]')
return elements.length > 0
```